# Create an object from firebase database

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using firebase to store user records. When a user logs in, I am trying to pull the record and create a user object to pass around amongst the view controllers as opposed to hitting the database multiple times.

```
class User: NSObject {
    var name: String?
    var email: String?
}
```

I have a variable, `myUser: User?` in my controller and would like to assign the record retrieved from firebase to that variable.

```
func retrieveUserWith(uid: String) {
    Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
            let user = User()

            user.name = dictionary["name"] as? String
            user.email = dictionary["email"] as? String

            self.myUser = user
        }
    })
}
```

Now I understand that the firebase call is asynchronous and I can't directly assign the created user to `myUser` variable as shown above.

Is there another way to assign `user` to `myUser` to avoid hitting the database every time I switch view controllers?

Answer (score 1):

This is not really the correct way to get the info you want.  Firebase already offers a sharedInstance of the User.

```
if let user = Auth.auth().currentUser {
      let name = user.displayName // should check that this exists
      let email = user.email // should check that this exists
}
```

Nonetheless, to achieve this the way you are looking to do so:

```
 class User: NSObject {
        var name: String
        var email: String?

        static var sharedInstance: User!

        init(name: String, email: String) {
             self.name = name
             self.email = email
        }

    }
```

Calls to firebase are asynchronous, so you should have a completionHandler that will get called when the call is finished:

```
    func retrieveUserWith(uid: String, completionHandler: @escaping () -> ()) {
        Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

            if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {

                let name = dictionary["name"] as? String ?? ""
                let email = dictionary["email"] as? String ?? ""

                let user: User = User(name: name, email: email)
                User.sharedInstance = user
                completionHandler()
            }
        })
    }
```

Then to use the sharedInstance of the user elsewhere in your app you can do the following:

```
if let user = User.sharedInstance {
     // do stuff here
}
```

Comment: I can't use the firebase method. Although, I only listed name and email in the question, I have many other properties and no way to access them using firebase's authorization methods.

As far as the completion handler, that is what I am currently trying to improve on. I make the database call and setup of the controller using the completion handler. When the user changes controllers, I have to hit the database with another request.

Comment: Make the call in AppDelegate, then use the sharedInstance throughout difference viewControllers.

Comment: This isn't working. When the app first opens, I need to be setting up the navbar using the logged in users information. Although I can create a shared instance, the shared Instance is nil at run time.

Comment: This is because the call to firebase is asynchronous.  You should not present the ViewController that needs the user info until after it has been retrieved.  You can point the initial viewController of the app to some dummy view controller and then present or change root view controller.  I will add in answer to show example.